# Unreal crashing on boot, only using cubegrid tool and landscape modelling. Consistent boot crashes,

Tags: crash, unreal-engine5

Assertion failed: LandscapeGuid.IsValid() [File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Landscape\Private\Landscape.cpp] [Line: 3218]

UnrealEditor_Landscape
UnrealEditor_Landscape
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_SceneOutliner
UnrealEditor_LevelEditor
UnrealEditor_LevelEditor
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_LevelEditor
UnrealEditor_LevelEditor
UnrealEditor_LevelEditor
UnrealEditor_LevelEditor
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_Slate
UnrealEditor_MainFrame
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
kernel32
ntdll

Quite lost here, project would occasionally crash randomly as is, not a hardware issue I don't think unless it's spiking my ram to kingdom come every so often. Project is still very much at the beginning so not sure as to why it's crashing. Let alone on boot so I can't even open the project. - newbie to unreal